# customize "dpi button" for multi-button mouse

Tags: windows, mouse

I dont use different settings of dpi so I dont use dpi button on my mouse. It can be nice to find a program to customize this button and set a specific action.

Unfortunately x-button (which is a superb program) doesn't recognize this button so I am looking for alternative solution.

I prefer gratis program working on windows.

Comment: What brand is the mouse?

Comment: [Anker vertical mouse](http://www.amazon.com/Anker-Ergonomic-Vertical-Adjustable-Controls/dp/B018LPBCDO/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1455705147&sr=8-3-fkmr0&keywords=anker+new+wired+vertical+mouse)