# Customize combination of multi-button mouse and keyboard

Tags: windows, gratis, mouse

I am looking for a program that can allow me to set deliberate action for pressing mouse and keyboard buttons. For instance win key + Wheel up can be set to Volume up.

I prefer a gratis program for windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com) is available for free and can be used to create a wide range of keyboard and mouse shortcuts, hotkeys, and macros.

The syntax to set the Volume Up with WinKey + Wheel Up would be `#WheelUp::Send {Volume_Up}`. After installing AutoHotKey, enter that into a blank text document and save it a 'fileNameHere'.ahk, then double click to run it.

While I am not using it currently, I have used AutoHotKey quite extensively in the past. Check out my [GitHub](https://github.com/MichelfrancisBustillos/AutoHotKey-Scripts) for some examples of what you can do.

Comment: Thank you for answer.  I made following code as you suggested: `#WheelUp::Send {Volume_Up}`   
`#Wheeldown::Send {Volume_Down}` and it works. the only problem is that windows start menu also open up at the same time. Is there any way to disable start menu pop up during execution of code?

Comment: I have done quite a bit of AutoHotKey work since this answer (actually got back into it because of this question). Unfortunately, when using the mouse with the WindowsLogoKey, it seems the menu will always pop up.

Comment: yes, better use ctrl, shift or alt.. thanks and good luck with coding!

Comment: also pls take a look at this question, maybe you have a solution with ahk?http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/29889/customize-dpi-button-for-multi-button-mouse

Comment: @Woeistg unfortunately, the dpi button on most mice changes internal firmware settings and it's being pressed is never sent to the computer. This means AHK cannot see or utilize it.